# VLookup to return MAX value from multiple hits

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I tried to vlookup the max value of available Qty against the material in another sheet which has below format. some one who can correct the way I work will be of much help.

What I tried but doesn't work

```
=INDEX('[Report.xlsb]Stock Report'!$L:$W,MATCH(D19,'[Report.xlsb]Stock Report'!$L$1:$L$9837,0),MAX(12))
```

WB-1

[image: Workbook1]

WB-2

[image: Workbook2]

Comment: If you have Excel 2019 or 365, could try Maxifs.

Comment: did that as well. similar one. but didn't work. 

`=MAX(IF(A:A=A1,C:G))`

Comment: Should be a single column though, like =MAX(IF(A:A=A1,C:C)) ? Perhaps try without full-column references.

Comment: `=MAX(IF('[Report.xlsb]Stock Report'!$L$1:$L$9837=D19,'[Report.xlsb]Stock Report'!$M$1:$M$9837))` I'm only guessing this to be the correct range references judging from your own attempt.

Answer (score 0):

If the table with available quantity is in cells A1 to B12 then:

```
=vlookup(C3,A$1:B$12,2,0)
```

Assuming the first case CH244G is in cell C3

Comment: sorry but I dont think this will give the max value!!

Comment: @Raags well you can think about using top and aggregate which can work - used it to get absences with names and cope with duplicates - but Îm on a smartphone so you can have a go.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the maximum value for each material, you could use a MAXIFS formula like this:

```
=MAXIFS('WB-2'!B:B,'WB-2'!A:A,'WB-1'!A2)
```

The first conditions is the range in which you're trying to find the maximum (i.e., the available quantity).  The second condition is the criteria range that lines up with the max range (i.e., the material on WB-2).  The third condition is the criteria (the material on WB-1).

It works the same as a SUMIFS, but returns only the maximum value instead of the sum. Similarly, MINIFS returns only the minimum value.

Also, note that the criteria and sum range are reversed for the SUMIF vs SUMIFS.  If you're accustomed to the SUMIF, it's easy to get mixed up when you switch to SUMIFS, MAXIFS, or MINIFS.